# Do not show Mac Mail headers when forwarding, but do show in Inbox

Tags: mail.app, email

Is there a way to view the detailed header of an email in Mac Mail without having to include all that detailed info when forwarding an email?

I am periodically interested in the header information from emails so I want to keep the option of viewing those details in my Inbox. However, I do not want to have Mail include that information in forwarded emails.

Most solutions posted online suggest going to `Preferences → Viewing → Show header detail` but this prevents me from viewing header details in my Inbox. Is there a way for me to have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detailed Header view is a Menu bar Icon (you can set it up) that allows you to view headers from Received emails.

To set it up right click on the mail menu bar and choose Customize.

From the new screen drag the "All Headers" icon to your menu bar.

Without some serious hacking, any email you send will also include the extended header information, same way as you can see it.

Comment: Thank you! By adding this icon in the menu bar, I can set the header detail view to default for my forwarded emails and just click this icon for the occasional instances when I want to know the whole header.